# VS Code the keyboard shortcut ctrl + space does not work (Mac Os)

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code
Usage
You can view a list of id and class attribute suggestions via ctrl + space.
In "type", highlighting empty quotes and pressing ctrl + space, nothing happens (tried commands and controls + space)

HTML CSS Support Extension

Answer (score 2):

If your OS Macos press "option & Esc"